# Python: porque ao declarar o construtor da Filha também tenho que declarar o construtor da Mãe?

Tags: python, kivy, superclasse

Estou desenvolvendo uma pequena aplicação em Python e me deparei com uma questão que não consegui tirar uma conclusão concreta sobre o porque disso acontecer. De maneira simples o problema é o seguinte:

O seguinte código funciona normalmente:

```
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

  class MyKeyboardListener(Widget):    
      pass     

  class Aplicativo(App):  
      def build(self):  
          return MyKeyboardListener()

  if __name__ == '__main__':  
      Aplicativo().run()
```

O problema de fato aparece quando crio o método construtor da classe, nesse caso a aplicação não mais funciona

```
  from kivy.app import App  
  from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

  class MyKeyboardListener(Widget)
      def __init__(self): <-- após incluir este o problema acontece
            pass

  class Aplicativo(App):  
      def build(self):  
          return MyKeyboardListener()  
  if __name__ == '__main__':  
      Aplicativo().run()
```

A aplicação só volta a funcionar quando eu chamo o método construtor da mãe, neste caso "Widget"

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyKeyboardListener(Widget)
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__(): <-- Construtor da Mãe

class Aplicativo(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return MyKeyboardListener()

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    Aplicativo().run()
```

A pergunta em questão é porque o programa para de funcionar quando declaro o construtor(mesmo que vazio) da classe MyKeyBoardListener? e porque o mesmo volta a funcionar quando chamo o construtor da super classe?

Comment: o construtor da classe mãe deve iniciar variaveis ou fazer a chama de algum metodo que seta algum parametro dentro do objeto, vc declarando o construtor da classe da classe filha vai sobre escrever o herdado, por isso ñ funciona sem a chamada super()

Comment: E por que você acha que não deveria ou não precisaria declarar?

Comment: vc só declara se quiser colocar funções extra, no caso do script de exemplo nada é adicionado ou mudado, logo codigo sem utilidade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No primeiro caso você automaticamente carrega e sobrescreve os atributos da sua classe com a herança do Widget.

No segundo caso não funciona, pois você carrega `__init__` da sua classe e sobrescreve o `__init__` da classe que você herdou.

Para resolver isso, é necessário o construtor `super().__init__()` dentro do `__init__` da sua classe criada para herdar os atributos da classe herdada.

Por exemplo, você criando uma classe com o método `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

É o mesmo que você evitasse chamar os métodos e atributos inicializadores do Widget que é composto dessa maneira:

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Before doing anything, ensure the windows exist.
        EventLoop.ensure_window()

        # Assign the default context of the widget creation.
        if not hasattr(self, '_context'):
            self._context = get_current_context()

        no_builder = '__no_builder' in kwargs
        self._disabled_value = False
        if no_builder:
            del kwargs['__no_builder']
        on_args = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k[:3] == 'on_'}
        for key in on_args:
            del kwargs[key]

        self._disabled_count = 0

        super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Create the default canvas if it does not exist.
        if self.canvas is None:
            self.canvas = Canvas(opacity=self.opacity)

        # Apply all the styles.
        if not no_builder:
            rule_children = []
            self.apply_class_lang_rules(
                ignored_consts=self._kwargs_applied_init,
                rule_children=rule_children)

            for widget in rule_children:
                widget.dispatch('on_kv_post', self)
            self.dispatch('on_kv_post', self)

        # Bind all the events.
        if on_args:
            self.bind(**on_args)
```

Por isso o correto é realizar a chamada do `__init__` com `super().__init__`.

Referência: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/_modules/kivy/uix/widget.html